# Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3

Tags: descriptor, artifact, logback-classic

I am getting below error -

Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)

Comment: Add below dependency and this should resolve this issue.

<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependency and this should resolve this issue.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```